# Regarding tree view, is it possible to have an on click function for the tree view

Tags: javascript, echarts

I'm wondering if it's possible to have a custom on click function on the leaves of the tree view in ECharts?
I've look at the docs, but couldn't find any thing on it.

As seen in the image, node where the arrow is pointing, is where i will like to have an on click function

[sample tree img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uog1m.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please specify what exactly do you mean by leaves? Technically any node except first is a leaf.

1. If you need to handle click on specific node then before process event you need strictly check for equivalence target node by name.

```js
// Params object that will passed to our event listener looks like

{
  // ...
  componentIndex: 0,
  componentSubType: "tree",
  componentType: "series",
  data: {
    name: "MergeEdge", // <-------- our target clicked node 
    value: 743
  },
  // ...
}

// Handle click event
myChart.on('click', function(params){
  var data = params.data
  if(data.name === 'MergeEdge'){ // <-------- node name test
    // test passed
    // doing something useful
  }
});
```

2. If you need to handle click on specific node group then you should neatly named nodes. Suppose a chart has three (without root) levels and you only need to handle clicks from the second level.

Let's prepare the data so that nodes of the same level named are similar way:

```js
data: [{
  "name": "root",
  "children": [{
    "name": "node_first_level_01",
    "children": [{
        "name": "node_second_level_01", // <-------- this
        "children": [{
          "name": "node_third_level_01",
          "value": 3938
        }]
      },
      {
        "name": "node_second_level_02", // <-------- this
        "children": [{
          "name": "node_third_level_02",
          "value": 3938,
        }]
      },
      {
        "name": "node_second_level_03", // <-------- this
        "children": [{
          "name": "node_third_level_03",
          "value": 3938,
        }]
      }
    ]
  }]
}],
```

Now take the function from the first example and instead of a strict check, we will check for compliance with the regular expression:

```js
// Handle click event
myChart.on('click', function(params){
  var data = params.data
  var rule = /\w+second\w+/gm; // <-------- regex rule
  if(rule.test(data.name)){    // <-------- test name
    // test passed
    // doing something useful
  }
});
```

Comment: Was actually looking at the last layer of node in the tree.

Thanks for helping again. Your answer help solve my problems.

Comment: Forgot to mention: instead `name` that will shown as node label on chart you can use `id` that is not shown anywhere.